# Notepad++ replace everything after "\n" with nothing

Tags: notepad++

I believe I'm having issues replacing everything after \n because it means it's a new line or something?

I would like to turn this:

```
Hey my name is james\nand I never learned how to read.
Hi I have a headache\nand it's getting worse.
Do geese see god?\nDoes god see goose
```

Into this:

```
Hey my name is james
Hi I have a headache
Do geese see god?
```

Using notepad++ search and replace.

Answer (score 1):

If you really have the 2 characters `\` and `n`, you can do:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\\n.*$`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\\          # a backslash, have to be escaped
n           # n  character
.*          # 0 or more any character but newline
$           # end of line
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]